# How do I check for ~ application/x-trash files

Tags: shell-script

I have this simple bash script to check for ~ application/x-trash files within a directory and its subdirectories.

It works fine, but it echoes empty *.*~ too, which seems to be harmless but annoying. How do I avoid that?

Script

```
#!/bin/sh
cd '/var/www/html/mypath/'
for d in $(find '/var/www/html/mypath/' -maxdepth 6 -type d)
do

echo $d
for f in  $d'/'*.*~; 
    do  FILE=$f;
        echo 'file to be removed:  '$FILE
    done
done
```

For a subdirectory dir, if there is not a ~ file into dir, at the terminal I get anyway:

> file to be removed:   /var/www/html/mypath/../../../dir/*.*~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to find any file whose name matches either `*~` or `.*~` (these are usually backup files left behind by an editor), then this single `find` invocation will do that for you:

```
find /var/www/html/mypath/ -type f \( -name '*~' -o -name '.*~' \) -print
```

You can insert a `-maxdepth 6` in there if you think it makes sense:

```
find /var/www/html/mypath/ -maxdepth 6 -type f \( -name '*~' -o -name '.*~' \) -print
```

To delete the found files, just add `-delete` to the end of the command.

---

When the shell can not expand a filename globbing pattern to a list of names, it is retained as an unexpanded pattern.  This is why you get the result you get with your code.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Do you happen to know if there is a way to fix my code too, say something like: `for f in  $d'/'\( -name '*~' -o -name '.*~' \);`?

Comment: @mario The `find` in my answer replaces the two `for` loops in your code, thereby fixing it. For your second loop to ignore printing unexpanded patterns, you would have to compare the value of `$FILE` to that of the pattern for equality, and also make sure there is no file with that name.

Answer (score 0):

the following does what I need:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd '/var/www/html/mypath/'

for i in `find '/var/www/html/mypath/' \( -name '*~' -o -name '.*~' \) -type f`; do

    echo 'file to be removed:  '$i
    mv $i   '/var/www/html/trashTest'
done
```